# How to pass password to scp command used in bash script?

Tags: bash, password, scp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Connect through SSH and type in password automatically, without using a public key](https://serverfault.com/questions/132405/connect-through-ssh-and-type-in-password-automatically-without-using-a-public-k)

I have a bash script that makes dump of DB then copies file from one server to another but it always asks for password before connection.

```
scp file.tar.gz root@xxx.xxx.xxx.194:/backup
```

Is there a way to pass password directly into script ?

Comment: http://www.how2s.org/index.php/Howto_use_scp_without_password_prompt_%28batch_mode%2C_scp_-B%29

Comment: Also, [answered on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/50096/7552)

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/132405/connect-through-ssh-and-type-in-password-automatically-without-using-a-public-ke

Comment: This is something I really hate about many online communities; They will tell you that you are doing something stupid and then not give you the answer.

Answer (score 97):

Use the tool [sshpass](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/sshpass)

```
sshpass -p 'password' scp file.tar.gz root@xxx.xxx.xxx.194:/backup
```

Comment: This is not a standard part of OpenSSH, and literally none of my machines (Mac OS X 10.7, Ubuntu 12.04, FreeBSD 8, Debian 3.1) have it.  It's also the accepted answer provided on the question that this one is marked as a duplicate of...

Comment: Excellent! Security isn't always a concern, such as during cross-platform development of a box within the firewall. On systems with apt-get, install with `sudo apt-get install -y sshpass`

Comment: OK, to add extra security, consider `sshpass -f file_with_password`. Then secure the password file's permissions, make it work, and then read some "clever" advice about how using sshpass is bad, and authorized_keys is great. Especially, when somebody else just gives you login+pass (e.g. for SFTP), and no option to authorize your public key...

Comment: I recommend reading the password from prompt once with `read -s -p "Enter ssh password : " PASSWORD_SSH;` and then use that in the sshpass phrase `sshpass -p $PASSWORD_SSH scp file.tar.gz root@xxx.xxx.xxx.194:/backup `

Answer (score 45):

Rather than using root create an account just for this job. Use public keys without a passphrase instead of passwords.

```
scp -i /home/backupuser/.ssh/id_rsa backupuser@xxx.xxx.xxx.194:/backup
```

By using a special account for the backup on the destination system you are not exposing your root password.

Comment: +1 for referring a creation of a specific account for file uploads instead of using root. And I will also recommend using a restricted shell like [rssh](http://www.pizzashack.org/rssh/) for this user.

Comment: -1 for not answering the question.

Comment: +nitpick for recommending another solution to the posed problem even though it does not literally answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

It's better to set up ssh to used key-based authentication rather than trying to figure out how to send text to the login process with something like `expect`.

Take a look at:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

So, basically, run `ssh-keygen -t dsa` on the machine that will run your script.  When it asks you for a passphrase, hit ENTER to accept a blank.  You will get two files.  If you followed the default suggestions, the files will be ~/.ssh/id_dsa and ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub.  The first one is the private key.  The second one is the public key.

Copy the public key to the second server using `ssh-copy-id user@server2`.  This will add the public key to the authorized_keys file of the user on server2.

You should now be able to run ssh from the first machine and log in without a password.

For copying the files, scp or rsync are fine.  It depends on what you're doing.  rsync will use ssh by default, so will use the key-based authentication you just set up.

Answer (score 3):

`scp` uses `SSH` to tunnel to a remote server and transfer files. `SSH` can authenticate users with a password, an `SSH` key or both (recommended).

To transfer files without a password, [create an `SSH` key](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2005/11/10/ssh-with-keys/) for the user you're going to use (root is *not* recommended, use an unprivileged user instead and have a job on the target server as root to perform the privileged action).

Then you need to configure the target system's `SSH` daemon to accept `SSH` key connections (also in above link).

Bear in mind that compromised `SSH` keys without a password are the same as compromised passwords - anybody can get in. For real users, it's better to double the security and require the key and a password.

Answer (score 3):

[pscp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pscp) allows you to pass the password to it directly using the -pw argument. Alternately, and this is a better idea, use ssh agent and set up key based logon - this is more secure. There's a howto on setting up ssh to use key based [logon](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) here

You can use the [yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_%28Unix%29) command to send a yes to the program.

Comment: this was a great fix to the problem of getting ssh keys onto 16 vms, most answer just say 'use keys' leading to having to manually login to each server to add a key when we need to set them up in large groups.Running this on bash on windows looks like  `PSCP.EXE -l $username -pw $password localflie "$HOST:/tmp/remotefile"`

Answer (score 2):

You should **not use** password-less ssh-keys for security reasons.

The tool [`keychain`](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/keychain-guide.xml) can help you re-use the ssh-agent and run rsync over ssh in scripts without being prompted for passwords.

To install it on a Ubuntu machine just run the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install keychain
```

Check out the [manpage for keychain](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/keychain.1.html) for more information on how to use it.