# How write .sh script to remote copy files between linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scp, files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass password to scp command used in bash script?](https://serverfault.com/questions/318474/how-to-pass-password-to-scp-command-used-in-bash-script)

when use scp to remote copy file between servers then type "YES" and "PASSWORD"
I don't know how to auto type it.

Can we use with rsync? And How?

Thanks